# Generate Makefile with clean rule that removes project executable

Tags: qt, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I want my QtCreator project to have a Makefile with a "`make clean`" rule that deletes the executable.

Normally, when making a Makefile for a simple C++ project, I would put this rule in the Makefile, where neatprogram is the executable (on Linux):

```
clean:
    rm -f neatprogram
```

But QtCreator uses `qmake` to generate a Makefiles for me. By default, it even adds a `clean` rule to the Makefile! But it only removes object files and such. How can I make it so the Makefile generated by `qmake` also removes (deletes) the single executable file for my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a predefined target `distclean` which removes all generated files including an executable. But note that `Makefile` itself will also be removed.

Alternatively, you can define your own target like this:

> myproject.pro

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += myclean
#myclean.target = myclean
myclean.depends = clean
myclean.commands = -$(DEL_FILE) $(DESTDIR_TARGET)
```